# Merge or Bind_rows just only new data - R

Tags: mysql, r, database, dataframe

Im working with a transaction data set, new data is update every in a Daily-Monthly file. Actually i'm load Historical and Daily files (10 files), then processed and finally created a Full data (Last year sales + current year sales), this procces takes 20 min every day.

Now i want to change the process, load Full data (1 file) and then add new data. This works much faster, like 2 min. The problem is the next one:

- FULL data contains 2021 Sales + January 2022 Sales.
- New data contains January 2022 Sales + February Sales.

when I merge the data with the following code, i lost data, because in FULL data exists duplicate data (this is correct).

```
DATA <- bind_rows(FULL, Daily)%>%distinct()
```

Here is an example of what I need:

FULL DATA:

| Sales ID | Sales Order | SKU | Price | Quantity | Description | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC1 | 123452 | 100 | 1 | Tshirt | 21-12-31 |
| ABCD | ABCD | 12345 | 200 | 2 | Shoes | 21-12-31 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE1 | ERROR | -100 | 1 | Devolution | 22-01-01 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE1 | ERROR | -100 | 1 | Devolution | 22-01-01 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE1 | ERROR | -100 | 1 | Devolution | 22-01-01 |
| FGH | FGH1 | 12412 | 10 | 1 | Socks | 22-01-02 |
| FGH | FGH1 | 12112 | 10 | 1 | Socks | 22-01-02 |

DAILY DATA:

| Sales ID | Sales Order | SKU | Price | Quantity | Description | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FGH | FGH1 | 12412 | 10 | 1 | Socks | 22-01-02 |
| FGH | FGH1 | 12112 | 10 | 1 | Socks | 22-01-02 |
| FGHRT | FGHRT1 | 12112 | 100 | 1 | Shoe | 22-01-03 |
| FGHRT | FGHRT1 | 12342 | 10 | 2 | Backpack | 22-01-03 |
| FGHRTY | FGHRTY1 | 126342 | 1000 | 1 | Bag | 22-01-04 |
| FGHRUT | FGHRUT3 | 121534 | 107 | 2 | Tshit | 22-01-04 |

Final Output (Just add bold data)

| Sales ID | Sales Order | SKU | Price | Quantity | Description | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC1 | 123452 | 100 | 1 | Tshirt | 21-12-31 |
| ABCD | ABCD | 12345 | 200 | 2 | Shoes | 21-12-31 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE1 | ERROR | -100 | 1 | Devolution | 22-01-01 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE1 | ERROR | -100 | 1 | Devolution | 22-01-01 |
| ABCDE | ABCDE1 | ERROR | -100 | 1 | Devolution | 22-01-01 |
| FGH | FGH1 | 12412 | 10 | 1 | Socks | 22-01-02 |
| FGH | FGH1 | 12112 | 10 | 1 | Socks | 22-01-02 |
| **FGHRT** | **FGHRT1** | **12112** | **100** | **1** | **Shoe** | **22-01-03** |
| **FGHRT** | **FGHRT1** | **12342** | **10** | **2** | **Backpack** | **22-01-03** |
| **FGHRTY** | **FGHRTY1** | **126342** | **1000** | **1** | **Bag** | **22-01-04** |
| **FGHRUT** | **FGHRUT3** | **121534** | **107** | **2** | **Tshit** | **22-01-04** |

Comment: Your code explicitly removed duplicates. `distinct()` returns only distinct values. If you don't want that, remove it

Comment: I know that, i need remove duplicates from Daily data and keep duplicates from Full data

Comment: Separate files?  No wonder it is taking minutes instead of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge()` for that.

```
merge(full_data, daily_data, all = T)

   Sales.ID Sales.Order    SKU Price Quantity Description     Date
1       ABC        ABC1 123452   100        1      Tshirt 21-12-31
2      ABCD        ABCD  12345   200        2       Shoes 21-12-31
3     ABCDE      ABCDE1  ERROR  -100        1  Devolution 22-01-01
4     ABCDE      ABCDE1  ERROR  -100        1  Devolution 22-01-01
5     ABCDE      ABCDE1  ERROR  -100        1  Devolution 22-01-01
6       FGH        FGH1  12112    10        1       Socks 22-01-02
7       FGH        FGH1  12412    10        1       Socks 22-01-02
8     FGHRT      FGHRT1  12112   100        1        Shoe 22-01-03
9     FGHRT      FGHRT1  12342    10        2    Backpack 22-01-03
10   FGHRTY     FGHRTY1 126342  1000        1         Bag 22-01-04
11   FGHRUT     FGHRUT3 121534   107        2       Tshit 22-01-04
```

Comment: It worked, but I still have some duplicate data, I'm checking the reason